# How to plot a variable with respect to another without separating the variable in an equation?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot θ23 wrt δ without separating θ23

```
2 E^(-I δ) Sec[θ12]^2 (-(1/4) E^(2 I δ) (7 + Cos[8 θ12]) Cos[θ23]^2 Sec[2 θ12]^2
  + 8 E^(2 I δ) Cos[δ] Cos[θ12] Cos[θ23] Sin[θ12] Sin[θ13] Sin[θ23]
  - Sin[θ13] ((1 + 4 E^(2 I δ) + 2 E^(4 I δ) + Cos[4 θ12]) Sin[θ13] Sin[θ23]^2
  - E^(I δ) (1 + E^(2 I δ) - 2 Cos[2 θ12]) Sin[2 θ12] Sin[2 θ23]))
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without separating theta23".  In order to plot a function, all variables except the independent variable that you are plotting against need to be specified.  In addition, you have a complex function here, so what kind of plot are you expecting?  The real and imaginary parts? Is this really an implicit equation that relates $\delta$ and $\theta23$? If so, I see no equation.  Please edit your post to clarify what you are actually asking for, and then, if you can, show what you have tried to do so that we have some idea of where you are in your understanding.

Comment: If there were an equation and not just an expression one would exploit `ContourPlot` setting a value for `θ12` or `ContourPlot3D` in general.  Nonetheless there is no equation.

Comment: In addition, I made some edits to your post.  It's worth checking that I didn't change the meaning of your expression.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: By  "without separating theta23" I mean not expressing theta23 in terms of  δ.  And I want a scatter plot by specifying the range of all the other parameters including δ.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

f[δ_, θ12_, θ13_, θ23_] = 
  2 E^(-I δ) Sec[θ12]^2 (-(1/4) E^(2 I δ) (7 + 
        Cos[8 θ12]) Cos[θ23]^2 Sec[2 θ12]^2 + 
     8 E^(2 I δ) Cos[δ] Cos[θ12] Cos[θ23] \
Sin[θ12] Sin[θ13] Sin[θ23] - 
     Sin[θ13] ((1 + 4 E^(2 I δ) + 2 E^(4 I δ) + 
           Cos[4 θ12]) Sin[θ13] Sin[θ23]^2 - 
        E^(I δ) (1 + E^(2 I δ) - 
           2 Cos[2 θ12]) Sin[2 θ12] Sin[2 θ23]));

f[1., 1., 1., 1.] *)

(* -2.42486 - 19.5143 I

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Abs[f[δ, θ12, θ13, θ23]],
  {δ, -1, 1}, {θ23, -Pi, Pi},
  FrameLabel ->
   (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {δ, θ23}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{θ12, 1}, -Pi, Pi, Pi/100., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{θ13, 1}, -Pi, Pi, Pi/100., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]